# How to display current date using full calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am new to jquery.
I am using full calendar for showing events for a month.
However I am unable to display current date above the calendar as shown in various example.

Below is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {     
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultView: 'month',
        editable: false,
        eventSources: [
            {
                url: '/Admin/AjaxRequest/CalendarDate/',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    start: '0',
                    end: '0',
                    id:id
                },
            },
        ]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[Titleformat](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/text/titleFormat/) and [Header](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/header/) documentations have all the answers you need.

Set a header where you specify where you want your title and then specify in titleformat how you want this title to be displayed.

Answering this even though @Xaerxess point in the comment is valid..